# Scaling Node boundaries properly across all screen sizes Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

[image: ]]

I am trying to set two SKSpriteNodes as boundaries(top / bottom) and anchor them to specific coordinates on the screen, so that when I switch from the iPhone 5 to the 6+, the boundaries are still in the same position. I also seem to be having a little trouble getting the node images to display properly. They are either zoomed in, or nonexistent on the screen.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
let size = CGRect(x: 100, y: 98, width:200, height:271)

bottomRectangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bottomRectangle")

bottomRectangle.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.3) // bottom center anchor points
bottomRectangle = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
bottomRectangle.zPosition = 3
bottomRectangle.size.height = self.size.height
bottomRectangle.size.width = self.size.width
bottomRectangle.position = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.3)
bottomRectangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: size)





self.addChild(bottomRectangle)

topRectangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "topRectangle")

topRectangle.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.8) // top center anchor points
topRectangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: size)
topRectangle.zPosition = 4
topRectangle.size.height = self.size.height
topRectangle.size.width = self.size.width
topRectangle.position = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.8)
```

self.addChild(topRectangle)

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene"){
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill




        // Configure the view.



        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */

       scene.size = skView.bounds.size
        skView.presentScene(scene)

    }
```

Comment: what is your scaleMode?

Comment: I edited my post to include my current scaleMode.

Comment: ok, now my next question is why are the anchor points in weird spots

Comment: I know you explain it in the question,  I just want to know why you are taking this approach,  is it only for what you described, or do you have something else planned with it

Comment: I needed to set the top and bottom rectangles to specific points and have them stay in the same location on all screen sizes. I will post a picture to help. I still have things to learn in swift, so my approach may not be the most efficient. This is for only what I described, I don't have something else planned with it.

Comment: you are doing resize fill though, this means there is more points(pixels) available inside the screen,  is this a result you want?  (I.E. it will take longer for an object to go from top to bottom on a 6+ than a 4s)

Comment: No, that is not the intended result. I will have to change the scaleMode. I am going to update my post now with a basic screenshot to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105022/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-seed12).

Comment: Well if that is the case then, your problem is solved, because your scene size wont change, so just set the bars to the top and bottom of your scene

Comment: If I change my scaleMode to Aspectfill and set the top bar to the top of the screen and the bottom bar to the bottom of the screen, it should give me the output that I am trying to achieve?

Comment: not the screen, the scene

Comment: Yes, the scene. Sorry, I had a typo. I will try that now and see how things go

Comment: I will keep you updated

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have updated my code. I am currently trying to correctly position the top and bottom bars to look like the image shown above. If I set the top / bottom bar boundaries to the top / bottom edges of the screen, will that keep an object from leaving the space in between the bars? I really appreciate your help, as I am still trying to get used to Swift.

Comment: I am confused here,  if you want your bars to be in a fixed position, just set it in that position (like set y = 1/4 the scene height).  As long as the object between the 2 bars is not moving at an insane speed, it will be contained

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have been very busy with work. I used to have the bars integrated with the background image, and set a boundary for both bars to be : let size = CGRect(x:100, y: 135.6, width: 200, height: 332.4). But the only issue was with the boundary coordinates changing with the different screen size. So I changed my approach to have each bar become it’s own SKSpriteNode and wanted to set each bar in a fixed position with their own boundary coordinates, and have the position and boundary coordinates stay the same for all screen sizes.

Comment: if you are using aspect fill then no matter what you do everything stays the same, because it scales and crops

Comment: Ah, I mean't to set it to Aspect fill but set Aspect Fit instead! Im going to revert back to my original approach without having each bar as it's own node, I am going to test this now.

Comment: same outcome,  aspect fit just gives you black bars

Comment: You were correct, the results did not change. I am back to my initial approach, without having to position each bar. The only problem that I have is getting these two lines of  code: let size = CGRect(x: 100, y: 98, width:200, height:271) self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: size)           to scale and work the same for all screen sizes. ( currently set for iPhone 5) That is the only problem that I have.

Comment: I am not understanding your problem here, they should be in the same spots, just scaled a little larger

Comment: I have the bars included in my background image, so there is no problem regarding the bars and their position. I have set invisible boundaries on the inner edges of the bars, so that it will contain an object between them. Shown in the code here:                                                                                        let size = CGRect(x: 100, y: 98, width:200, height:271)
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: size)

Comment: The problem that I am having is when I go from using an iPhone 5 display and scale to a larger display, like an iPhone 6 or 6+, the coordinates that I had set for the boundaries are slightly off because I am scaling to a larger display. So I was looking to set my invisible boundaries to be in the correct position regardless of the display size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105454/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-seed12).